# Where to place "IFERROR" and "SWITCH" in a formula

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I'm working on a personal project, this is a continuation of [this post here on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/10rl9gz/is_it_possible_to_say_that_an_emoji_equal_a_value/).

I'm struggling with the IFERROR and SWITCH functions. Why doesn't this formula work?

```
=AVERAGEIFS(J5:J,H5:H,A40,I5:I,A26(IFERROR(SWITCH(J5:J,"❤️",10,"",0),J5:J)))
```

[Document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ozr9wN-ULcUmKxDhrE-sPVOrnHvEaq-6GfyhEt3vSok/edit?usp=sharing)

What I'm trying to do:

- Make the average per platform and if it's a movie or a show and including the emojis as value. This is what I asked in my previous post.
- One question I have is: How can I make the average for a platform including everyone if someone hasn't seen something on one platform?

Comment: you don't need IFERROR around SWITCH, you can just set the default value to return blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added formula to your sheet `Cell B42`

```
=AVERAGE(IFNA(FILTER(IFERROR(SWITCH(J5:J,"❤️",10,"",0),J5:J),H5:H=A40,I5:I=A42)))
```

- Regarding your second query, I'd say to leave the person out maybe from the average score. his stat within the calculation cell would just be blank

Comment: Thanks this is perfectly working, thanks a lot :)